# Direction of a vector

Tags: matlab

If I have :

```
a=magic(9);
```

How do I compute the direction and magnitude of vectors between any two points in `a`? For example if I define `vec = [a(1,1) a(2,2)]`, would the direction of the vector be defined as: `vecdir = a(1,1) - a(2,2)`?

Comment: but a(1,1) and a(2,2) are scalars, so how can there be a direction between them? Do you mean the vector created by letting the X component be a(1,1) and the Y component be a(2,2)?

Comment: how do i create such a vector that you have mentioned?

Comment: as you said, vec = [a(1,1) a(2,2)]

Comment: in that case, how do i find the direction of vec as I have defined it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
vec = [x y]
dist = sqrt(sum(vec.^2)) % i.e. sqrt(x^2 + y^2)
dir = atan(y/x) % i.e. atan(vec(2) / vec(1))
```

Answer (score 8):

The correct way to compute the direction is to use `atan2()` instead of `atan()`, because `atan()` cannot resolve the quadrants and gives wrong angles in the second and third quadrant (i.e. when x is negative). As an example,

```
x = -1;
y = -1;
dir = atan(y/x);  % returns 0.78540 rad = 45 deg
```

Which is clearly the wrong direction. However, `atan2()` yields

```
dir2 = atan2(y, x); % returns -2.3562 rad = -135 deg.
```

If you insist on using `atan()`, you must check the sign of the x-argument and add `pi` whenever it is negative.