# Calculate angle between 2 geographic coordinates in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, coordinates, angle

I'm trying to calculate the angle between 2 geographic (Latitude,Longitude) points in MATLAB. The points are:
(-65.226,125.5) and (-65.236,125.433).

I used the MATLAB function, `azimuth`, as:

```
azimuth(-65.226,125.5,-65.236,125.433)
```

I convert the result to radians, and plotting this using `quiver`, I get the following plot:

[image: difference in azimuth]

I want the red vector to point from the top right dot to the bottom left dot.

The points are at fairly high latitude (~65S), and the separation of the points is low (about 0.1 degrees). Thus, I can't really understand how the curvature of the earth could affect the azimuth prediction that much..

Does anyone have any experience with `azimuth` in MATLAB, or have a better suggestion to calculating the angle between the coordinate pairs?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you not just treat them as cartesian vectors: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756539/direction-of-a-vector/11757780#11757780 ?

Comment: You almost reached Antarctica with these points!!!

Comment: I don't think you can treat them as cartesian... since they're on the sphere, so to speak?And yes, they're points along the continental shelf seas of Antarctica :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) you can detailed information and formulae on how to find angle between two latitude-longitude points.

Comment: So there was 2 issues here....
1) What I actually wanted was the 'rhumb line' - the bearing that is required to travel from point 1 to point 2, rather than the great circle bearing (which is a changing bearing).
2) Secondly, my issue was also compounded, because for some BIZARRE reason, in MATLAB, I needed to plot the horizontal and vertical components of the bearing as sin(angle),cos(angle) rather than cos(angle),sin(angle), as you'd expect. (I'm still confused by this.... a Bug perhaps?)